# Change event for combobox not getting fired in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am working in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). I have written code for displaying a combo box like this:

```
<select name="country" id="idCountry" class="clsCountry" >
    <?php foreach($objCountries as $objCountry):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $objCountry->getId()?>" ><?php echo $objCountry->getName()?>   </option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select></td>
```

For change event:

```
$("#idCountry").change(function(){ .... });
```

but change event is not getting fired. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is the jQuery change event in the document.ready handler? What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: The code that you posted seems fine. Maybe something else on the page is causing an error due to which the above code is never executed.

Comment: yeah i have put change event in document.ready handler ...i am using jquery 1.4

Comment: did you test on all browsers?

Comment: i have put combo box in div tag ... but it won't cause problem right? ... do u have any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: i have tested in IE and mozilla firefox ... it doesn't work there ...

Comment: any errors encountered on firebug (on change of selected option)?

Comment: no .. not getting any errors ...

Comment: my problem got solved ... i had put document.ready handler inside <?php slot('js')?> tag ... i removed this tag n now change event is getting fired ... thank you all ...

Answer (score 0):

First, is the code placed inside the ready function of the document?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     //code here
});
```

Or try this:

```
$("#idCountry").ready(function()
{
  $("#idCountry").change(function(){
    //code here
  });
});
```